# How to display letterhead Email Template using Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, apex-email-service

I am able to send an email from VF page, and am getting the emails with the proper text formatting, but I am not getting the letterhead associated to the email template that I am referencing. Is that even possible? Based on my research it seems like other folks have the same problem. My email template has letterhead that i would like to utilize, but it is not coming over with the email. Has anyone done anything similar?

```
EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [select Id, DeveloperName, HtmlValue, Body From EmailTemplate where DeveloperName = 'LTRO_Additional_Documents_Required'];
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////        
           String htmlBody = emailTemplate.HTMLValue;
           htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('NewEmail', emailBody);
           mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);
    ///////////////////////////////////////
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query the BrandTemplateId from the EmailTemplate object, and from there, you can query the [BrandTemplate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_brandtemplate.htm), which is in HTML form. You'll need to do some parsing via [Dom.Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm#!) or some other means, but it is certainly possible to gain access to the letterhead.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Would you happen to have an example of this? I did find something similar in my research, and did find out that I can query the brandTemplate, but not sure how I can incorporate that when I send the email out. This is where I get lost.